# How do you create an Image object from a MemoryStream in C# using iText7?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, itext7

I am working with iText7 in ASP.NET-MVC v5.2. I am very inexperienced with iText and C# am still trying to figure out how the classes in this library work.

Say I have a `MemoryStream` which contains an image...

```cs
MemoryStream imgStream = new MemoryStream(imgLocation);
```

How can I create an Image object using `imgStream`? I am looking for something along the lines of

```cs
Image img = new Image(imgStream);
```

Thanks for the help :)

**EDIT**: I am trying to create an Image from iText not `System.Drawing.Image`

Comment: The `itext` tag should only be used for versions up to 5.  See the tag description.

Comment: There is no `iText.IO.Image` class `Image`. In the namespace `iText.IO.Image` there is an `ImageData` class from which you can generate an `Image` from the `iText.Layout.Element` namespace.

Comment: @mkl thank you for clarifying. iText docs are starting to make a lot more sense lol.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To create an iText 7 `Image` object from a bitmap image, you first have to create an `ImageData` instance which you then can feed into one of the corresponding `Image` constructors

```
public Image(ImageData img);
public Image(ImageData img, float left, float bottom);
public Image(ImageData img, float left, float bottom, float width);
```

You usually create an `ImageData` instance using the corresponding `ImageDataFactory` static methods:

```
public static ImageData Create(byte[] bytes);
public static ImageData Create(String filename);
public static ImageData Create(Uri url);
```

As you see, there is no method for a stream. But as your stream is a `MemoryStream`, you can easily retrieve a `byte[]` of the image. Thus,

```
byte[] imageBytes = imgStream.ToArray();
ImageData rawImage = ImageDataFactory.Create(imageBytes);
Image image = new Image(rawImage);
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert the MemoryStream to a `byte[]` and use the `GetInstance` method

```
public static byte[] GetByteArray(Stream input)
{
    byte[] buffer = new byte[16*1024];
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        int read;
        while ((read = input.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
        {
            ms.Write(buffer, 0, read);
        }
        return ms.ToArray();
    }
}
```

and then use the byte array like this

```
var Image = Image.GetInstance(GetByteArray(imgStream));
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. The only thing I don't understand with this approach is why we need to create a function to get the byte array from the MemoryStream. Can we not just use `imgStream.ToArray()`?

Comment: @jordansandberg That's what Amy wanted to express in the first comment.

Comment: By the way, `Image.GetInstance` was the iText 5.x way, not the iText 7 way.

Comment: @mki yea `Image.GetInstance()` wasn't working for me

Comment: Sorry I couldn't help, I'll check up some more.

Comment: @Amy you are corrent, I will edit the answer with another approach, thanks.